# ternary is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I have this form below that has this radio button and the user can select if he wants to collect info "only for the guy that does the registration" or from "All participants" when a user does a registration in a conference.

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix"
  action="{{route('questions.update', ['conf_id' => $conf->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{csrf_field()}}

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Collect info</label>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="participants" id="not_all_participants" value="not_all_participants" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Only for the guy that does the registration
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="participants" id="all_partcipants" value="all_partcipants">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            All participants
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
...
</form>
```

I have a conference table that has the field "all_participants" and its a tinyint, if its 0 is to collect info only from the guy that does the registration and its 1 if its to collect info of each participant.

So I have a method to update this info. But it's not working, I have this ternary below but is not working, in the database is stored always "0".

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id){
        //dd($request->all());
        $conf = Conference::find($id);
        $conf->all_participants = ($request->participants == "all_participants" ? 1 : 0);
        $conf->save();
    }
```

Comment: might be because you wrote 'value="all_partcipants" ' ...there is an 'i' missing

Comment: You also have that typo in the `id`.

Comment: Outputting values? No, I'm sure I did no mistakes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are checking for 'all_participants' but in your form your value is 'all_partcipants'..notice the missing 'i'

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="participants" id="all_partcipants" value="all_partcipants">
```

Edit: as mentioned by @Barmer you also hav that typo in the id